# ListView filling items all the time in the adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

Following is my `ListView` adapter. You can see in it that there is a `FillData` function that fills data for the list item. I see that it is always called. Shouldn't the list and the `ListAdapter` fill one time per item? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class GlobalRecipeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Recipe> {

    private final static String mTAG = "GlobalRecipeListAdapter";

    private LayoutInflater  mInflater = null;
    private int mListViewItemResId  = -1;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader( CookTales.Instance() );

    public GlobalRecipeListAdapter(Context context, int resId, ArrayList<Recipe> items) {
         super(context, resId, items );
         mListViewItemResId = resId;
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate( mListViewItemResId, null );
            holder.recipePic = new DisplayableImageView( (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_RecipeImageViewId ) );
            holder.name = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById( R.id.name_entry );
            holder.author = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById( R.id.username_entry );
            holder.likes = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById( R.id.likes_entry );
            holder.diffculty = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_DifficultyImageViewId );
            holder.preparationTime = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_TimeImageViewId );
            holder.recipePic.GetImageView().setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener(getContext(), holder.recipePic)); 
                holder.name.setTypeface( CookTales.Fonts.ARIAL );
            holder.name.setTextSize(  CookTales.Fonts.RUNNING_TEXT_SIZE );
            holder.author.setTypeface(  CookTales.Fonts.ARIAL );
            holder.author.setTextSize(  CookTales.Fonts.RUNNING_TEXT_SIZE );
            holder.likes.setTypeface(  CookTales.Fonts.ARIAL );
            holder.likes.setTextSize(  CookTales.Fonts.RUNNING_TEXT_SIZE );
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if( super.getItem(position) != null) {
            if( position == 0 && position == getCount() - 1 ) {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_single );                } else if( position == 0 ) {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_up );
            }
            else if( position == getCount() - 1 ) {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_down );
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_middle );                }

            FillRecipeDataToHolder( position, holder );
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else  {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }    
        return convertView;
    }

    protected void FillRecipeDataToHolder(int position, ViewHolder viewHolder ) {
        viewHolder.name.setText( getItem(position).GetName() );
        viewHolder.author.setText( getItem(position).GetAuthor() );
        viewHolder.likes.setText( getItem(position).GetNumOfLikes() + " likes.");

        viewHolder.diffculty.setImageResource( Convertor.Difficulty2ImageResId( getItem(position).GetDifficulty(), mTAG ) );
        viewHolder.preparationTime.setImageResource( Convertor.Time2ImageResId( getItem(position).GetPreparationTime() ) );

        if( getItem( position ).GetRecipePicture().isValid() ){
            viewHolder.recipePic.GetImageView().setImageResource( Convertor.Category2ImageView( getItem( position ).GetCategory(), mTAG ) );
            mImageLoader.DisplayImage(  getItem( position ).GetRecipePicture().GetImageLocation(), 
                                        getItem( position ).GetRecipePicture().isUploaded() == false,
                                        getContext(), 
                                        viewHolder.recipePic );
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.recipePic.GetImageView().setImageResource( Convertor.Category2ImageView( getItem( position ).GetCategory(), mTAG ) );
        }
    }

    static protected class ViewHolder {
        DisplayableImageView    recipePic;
        TextView                name;
        TextView                author;
        TextView                likes;
        ImageView               diffculty;
        ImageView               preparationTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getView()`(and your `FillRecipeDataToHolder()` with it) method will be called every time the `ListView` will require a new view(because of the user scrolling the list up and down) to show on the visible screen.

If the user scrolls the list until the last element the method will be called for every item in the adapter, then if the user starts scrolling up again then the `getView()` method will also be called again for as many elements as the user scrolls(and your fill method will also be called every time).

Comment: But why the line:holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  is never called?

Comment: @user1136875 That line should be called because the list will recycle views. How exactly do you see it isn't called? Also `convertView.setTag(holder);` should be placed in the if clause after you inflate the `convertView`(if it is null).

Answer (score 1):

The framework only builds enough to fill the screen (to conserve memory and cpu cycles) when you use the standard list adapters.  You've built a custom one and are using a view holder, which is doing the same thing.

If you make a list that doesn't fill more than one screen I believe you would see the activity (or lac thereof) you are expecting.